# Is there a faster way to get notified of new questions than RSS?

Tags: support, feed

I wanted to use RSS to get notification of new questions. I set everything up only to be disappointed by the fact that there is a significant delay between the asking of a question and its being included in the feed. By significant I mean on the order of 5 minutes. For most questions I am interested in answering, the question has already been answered by the time I see it. It is not a matter of refreshing the feed too slowly. No matter how fast I refresh, I can see that there are questions that are not in the feed by manually refreshing the stackoverflow page in a browser. Even if I repeatedly refresh the feed, the new questions do no appear for sometimes more than 5 minutes.

Is there a faster alternative to RSS for seeing new questions (other than scraping the web page)?

Comment: What's the hurry?

Comment: The hurry is that the questions are answered by the time I see them and I cannot earn points because the person who asked the question selects the first "correct" answer, not mine.

Comment: I was not aware until now that there is an API. I have found api.stackexchange.com, but before I spend a lot of time setting something up, can someone tell me if the API data feed is updated any faster than the RSS feed? Or will I just be in the same situation?

Comment: it is allowed to poll for new questions every 60 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack Overflow does not have a live refresh on the newest questions page due to heavy traffic. But you can open all the tags you want to follow in a window. Just put in the search box your tags like this

```
[c] OR [java] OR [php] OR [ms-access*]
```

The newest tag questions tab has live refresh and you can see new questions the second they are asked in your browser tab.